# angularJs http Post issues: inserting data

Tags: angularjs

I've problems with inserting data using angularJs and Spring Boot, i've tested the url with postman and every thing is working except using angular's form.
the angular's controller

```
 function addCtrl($scope, $state, $http, $window) {
  
/***ajouter un hotel******/

$scope.AddItem = function AddItem() {
  console.log("clik");
  var nom = document.getElementById('nom').value;
  var localisation = document.getElementById('localisation').value;
  $http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost:1001/Hotel',
    params: {nom, localisation},
  })
}
```

the back end service

```
@PostMapping(value="/Hotel")public Hotel saveHotel1(@RequestBody Hotel h{h.getNom();h.getLocalisation();return HR.save(h);}
```

the result of the insert BECOME

```
"org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Required request body is missing "
```

still works with postman but not with angular's form the error become : "POST http://localhost:1002/Hotel?localisation=Tunis&nom=hotel "

Comment: What about changing params to data ? in your query ?

Comment: it works with data thank you soooooooooooo much thanks a loooooot